# Tampermonkey hello word script not working

Tags: tampermonkey

I just installed tampermonkey and the "hello world" script, and its not running.
I found no indications anywhere on how to proceed.
None of the rest of the scripts seems to be working.
What should I try?

(This question is mainly aimed to the creator, the stackoverflow user named derjanb)

Thank you.

EDIT: Editing after the downvote:
I did research before asking here. But there is no way to contact the author, so Im trying this. I searched for solutions in greasemonkey google groups, his forum, and tried to find his contact email without success. Then found some Tampermonkey questions and answers here on Stackoverflow and decided to post it here.
There is very few information on my question, but really, I found NO troubleshoot whatsoever referring to scripts simply not running.

Comment: Where did you get hello world script ?

Comment: you didn't even include the code. To say a hello world program doesn't say much re what the code is,  'cos there are different ways one might display something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this was such a basic thing.
I installed it also in Firefox, to see if something was wrong with my configuration.
After clicking around, I realized the firefox version changes color when clicked, and then got that if its grey, its off, if its colorful, it works.
Therefore, the reason it was not working in Chrome, is just that I had to click on the Tampermonkey icon then click the "enabled" tick...
Noobs mistake, but undocumented one.
Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: yeah it's confusing because i also thought the green "Enabled" checkmark meant you had to click it to enable tampermonkey (but it actually represents  tampermonkey's current status, which is enabled)